# Problems with positioning

Tags: css, html, border

When I zoom in and out, the gray in my background color goes over the red border. How do I stop this from happening?

My CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
    padding-top:30px;
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    height:2055px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:1050px;
    background-color: #090909;
    margin-top:15px;
}
.backgroound {
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    /* this gray goes over red border  */
    background-color: gray;
    height:1950px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width:985px;
}
.paa {
    background-color:black;
    font-size:40px;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    height:80px;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<header class="paa"> <a href="#">
    <img src="" alt="loggo">
</a>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <a class="vari" href="" id="home"><span  >Home</span></a> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="vari" href="" id="m">llls</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="backgroound"></div>
```

Comment: For one, you have invalid HTML and CSS.  CSS comments can only be of the style `/* comment */`, you can't have the double slash (`//`).  You're missing a closing `</a>` tag on your first anchor element: `<a href=""><img src="" alt="loggo">` needs the closing anchor after `<img>`.  Also, your code is incomplete.  Include the entire contents of your HTML file if you are ever unsure.  That way people can see if you made any really simple errors that would invalidate your HTML.

Comment: I like how the editor validated your CSS and HTML lol

Comment: thank you for your answer as i said i am beginner, and i forgot that we cannot comment in css with double slash. this unknown friend(Housamz)  solved my problem . thank you both

Answer (score 0):

So you need the grey div to be in the center of the red border?
if that's the case, add this line:

```
.background
    margin:auto;
}
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3uc9qm5

Comment: its still not working if you see the bottom the gray goes over red border

Comment: you have to zoom out then you will see it

Comment: I got it now, change margins for "body" & ".background" as follow:
    margin: auto auto 10px

Comment: what does auto do ? that didnt work but when i put more auto's

Comment: to body i put  margin: auto auto 10px;  and to ".background"    margin: auto auto auto auto 10px; now it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to shorten the height of `.backgroound`.

Either:

`height: 1830px;`

or

`height: 87%;`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/1q52w0jf/

Comment: here is not my full code but when i put the height: 87%; still it goes over red border,,, is here some chat system if i can send you

Comment: You will need to provide the full code, it works in my example all the way to 25% zoom.